# Save button on Logic App is disabled

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a logic app, this is trigger by a Twitter and analize the tweet text by cognitive services and storage the result on azure blob storage, all services is connected well but the save button is disable.

Answer (score 0):

We had a small bug last week where sometimes save wouldn't light up (with rest of top bar). We've shipped the fix but may need to clear cache and re open. Apologies for the inconvenience. If that doesn't work this week's build definitely should - [HTTP://aka.ms/logicapps-preview](http://HTTP://aka.ms/logicapps-preview)

Answer (score 0):

IE and Edge usually have this issue, use Chrome and you should see it enabled at all times